# how to install the flyway cli globally, not a java project

Tags: macos, flyway

I want use flyway as a command line tool with a directory of sql migration files. I'm not sure how to install it though.

I moved the command to `/usr/local/bin/flyway` but running it comes up with an error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.flywaydb.commandline.Main
```

So it seems I need to put jar files somewhere the command can find them. Where would that place be? I don't want the command in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untar the archive and add the whole installation directory to the PATH. Only moving the shell script will not work.

Comment: Works thank you. I dont love appending to the path for one command tho. Feels excessive.

Comment: You can always symlink to it as an alternative